# Looking for Artifactory Query Language example in Java

Tags: java, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I'm trying to use the Artifactory REST API (and in particular, the Artifactory Query Language) from a Java client but the examples on the site are written in Groovy (snippets) and it's not immediately clear how a Java client would work.

A Java example that uses the REST API (or the Artifactory Java Client API) to execute an AQL query would be very much appreciated.

For what it's worth, here's a link to the Artifactory Query Language site...

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language

Answer (score 8):

The Artifactory Java Client does not support AQL queries natively.
You can however use the generic Rest call interface it [provides](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/jfrog/artifactory/client/Artifactory.java) to create an [ArtifactoryRequest](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/jfrog/artifactory/client/ArtifactoryRequest.java) pointing to the AQL API [endpoint](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)).

The examples in the wiki you linked are not in Groovy they are in AQL syntax - you simply construct a String of whatever query you'd like and send it as the body of the request - roughly something like

```
String aqlQuery = "items.find({\"name\": {\"$match\" : \"*test.*\"}})";
Artifactory artifactory = Artifactory.create(url, userName, password);
ArtifactoryRequest aqlRequest = new ArtifactoryRequestImpl()
            .method(ArtifactoryRequest.Method.POST)
            .apiUrl("/api/search/aql")
            .requestBody(aqlQuery);
 //Parse this string as json
 String aqlResponse = artifactory.restCall(aqlRequest);
```

The response is a JSON you can parse and work on - check the example from the API link I provided.

Comment: I had to tweak line 2 to use the ArtifactoryClient class (as Artifactory is an interface)...

`Artifactory artifactory = Artifactory.create(url, userName, password);`

Comment: I also had to add .requestType and .responseType...

`
        ArtifactoryRequest aqlRequest = new ArtifactoryRequestImpl()
                    .method(ArtifactoryRequest.Method.POST)
                    .apiUrl("/api/search/aql")
                    .requestType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.TEXT)
                    .responseType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.JSON)
                    .requestBody(aqlQuery);
`

Comment: But still, I'm unable to get anything but...

groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found

Comment: I also had to change the apiUrl to "api/search/aql" (sans the leading forward slash). And I'm now seeing results! :-)

Comment: now it has: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java/tree/master/services/src/main/java/org/jfrog/artifactory/client/aql

Answer (score 1):

@fundeldman Thanks for suggesting the answer above. After a few minor tweaks, the code is now working. Here's the latest and greatest...

```
String aqlQuery = "items.find({\"name\": {\"$match\" : \"*rup-receipt*\"}}).include(\"repo\", \"path\", \"name\")";
Artifactory artifactory = ArtifactoryClient.create(artifactoryUrl, username, password);
ArtifactoryRequest aqlRequest = new ArtifactoryRequestImpl()
            .method(ArtifactoryRequest.Method.POST)
            .apiUrl("api/search/aql")
            .requestType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.TEXT)
            .responseType(ArtifactoryRequest.ContentType.JSON)
            .requestBody(aqlQuery);
Map<String, ?> aqlResponse = artifactory.restCall(aqlRequest);
```